# Using curl for lira API with a period in the fixVersion jql

Tags: post, curl, jira, jql

I've tried various iterations of using either ", ' and ` to enclose a curl query to an instance of jira in order to get all issues for a particular fix Version.

`curl -D- -u username:password -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jql":"project = PROJ AND fixVersion=Version-1.2.3"}' "https://thejirainstall.com/jira/rest/api/2/search"`

However, using this and a couple of other change on fixVersion such as:

```
fixVersion="Version-1.2.3"
```

or

```
fixVersion=\"Version-1.2.3\"
```

or

```
fixVersion=Version-1\u002e2\u002e3
```

Add and remove quotes at will.

The ones that don't fail outright return:

```
{"errorMessages":["Error in the JQL Query: '\\.' is an illegal JQL escape sequence. The valid escape sequences are \\', \\\", \\t, \\n, \\r, \\\\, '\\ ' and \\uXXXX. (line 1, character 38)"],"errors":{}}
```

How do I either escape periods `.` or add another set of quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out that Jira doesn't permit version names in jql syntax. The version `id` must be used instead.

And, in order to get the version id you must parse the result from `https://thejirainstall.com/jira/rest/api/2/project/ON/versions?`

This now means that I have to use a JSON parser anyway. So, now I'm using jq via `homebrew install jq`

My current solution is to write a bash script as below:

```
JIRA_FIXVERSION
fixVersionQuery='https://thejirainstall.com/jira/rest/api/2/project/ON/versions?';
myJSONResponse=`curl -u username:password -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" --insecure --silent $fixVersionQuery |jq '.[] | {id,name} | select(.name=="Version-1.2.3" | .["id"]'`; 
echo $myJSONResponse;
```